# Pressure Sensor stops delivering samples when screen is turned off

Tags: android, screen, sensors, wakelock, suspend

this is my first post here. Before asking my question I wanted to thank the team of this site and all the contributors. The info here really helped me a lot making my start into developing for Android.
Here's my problem: I wrote a small extension for DashClock that displays current altitude calculated from pressure sensor data. Everything works fine as long as the screen is turned on. But when the sceen turns off the pressure sensor stops delivering samples. I tried a lot but without success: setting a wakelock, unregister and reregister the SensorEventListener, putting it in a designated thread... Does anybody have a clue how to get this working? I dont need samples every second, every minute or so would be fine. Here are the relevant parts of my code: (RTC_WAKEUP -> AlarmReceiver.onReceive -> starts SensorService)

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("Alarm!");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, PressureSensorService.class));
    }
}

public class PressureSensorService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    final static String SENSOR_UPDATE_ACTION = "SENSOR_UPDATE_ACTION";
    private float pressure;
    private SensorManager mgr;
    private Sensor pressuresensor;
    Intent intent = new Intent("SENSOR_UPDATE_ACTION");
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        System.out.println("PressureSensorService created!");
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        System.out.println("PressureSensorService started!");
        mgr = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        pressuresensor = mgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);
        mgr.registerListener(this, pressuresensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        mgr.unregisterListener(this, pressuresensor);
        System.out.println("PressureSensorService stopped!");
    }
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        PressureSensorService.this.pressure = event.values[0];
        intent.putExtra("pressure", pressure);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        System.out.println("Pressure = "+ pressure + " hPa");
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```